# Qual a função do método populate no mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Estou com duvidas em entender a funcionalidade do método populate no mongoose

Comment: Pô cara, qual a dúvida? Tem que ter bola de cristal pra saber qual a sua dúvida.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ela é uma alternativa para o operador [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)

Imagine o cenário:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const pessoaSchema = Schema({
  _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  nome: String,
  idade: Number,
  historias: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Historia' }]
});

const historiaSchema = Schema({
  autor: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Pessoa' },
  titulo: String,
  fas: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Pessoa' }]
});

const Historia = mongoose.model('Historia', historiaSchema);
const Pessoa = mongoose.model('Pessoa', pessoaSchema);
```

Se você quer fazer uma busca em `Historia` pegando os dados do respectivo autor (ou seja, um `JOIN` no SQL), você pode usar a função `populate` para preencher a propriedade `autor` com os dados do autor em questão em vez de mostrar apenas o seu identificador:

```
Historia.
  findOne({ titulo: 'Exemplo' }).
  populate('autor')
```

[Documentação](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)